# Is there a Ruby gem that abstracts several social networking APIs into one simple API?

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, social-networking, abstraction

My team is building a site that would like to integrate with several social networks, such as Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, Google+, and more. The social network integreation, however, is not necessarily the core focus of the site and our team is small so we don't want to spend weeks on integration.

In terms of authentication, we're aware of the many options available to us. What we're looking for is an abstraction over the other social APIs, such as sharing status, getting lists of friends/connections, and getting the profile.

Basically, I'm wondering, is there a gem that is equivalent to the Janrain Engage service? (not the authentication pieces, mind you, the social API part)

Comment: Dear visitors and Stackoverflow newbies, if you would also like an answer to this question, please vote it up. Please do this for all other questions for which you would like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not answer your question: we opted to paying JanRain $$ to handle the login / auth stuff.

I fought with this for a while, but most of the companies -- fb especially -- are prone to changing APIs quickly and not being awesomone about backwards compatibility.  support can become a PITA.  even with 3rd party tools, they may not be updated in time... so your team can end up patching stuff to make things work.  i like the idea of calling up someone and yelling at them if they don't offer a timeline I like, referencing a SLA clause in a contract.

anyways, if you keep going that route and don't find a ruby gem,  you could at least port something from Python.  there are a handful of django plugins that handle abstraction, in addition to at least a half dozen other projects on PyPi -- including Velruse, which is decently maintained by Ben Bangert of Pylons , Beaker , etc.